# Sound card not detected by Ubuntu

Tags: sound

I have just switched from Windows 11 to Ubuntu and the sound card is not detected y the system at all. I tried all troubleshooting methods I could find but Ubuntu is just m=not seeing the sound card.

Those are the results of some of the commands I tried:
`aplay -l`
just returns
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
`lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` returns nothing
`inxi -A` returns
Audio:
Message: No device data found.
Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic running: yes
Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes

I'm new to using linux and not sure how to fix this.

Comment: From the version numbers it looks like you're using Ubuntu 22.04? What hardware is this? A laptop (what make/model?) or a desktop (what make/model of motherboard?)?

Comment: Look at the system startup logs with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. See how it detects your hsrdware

Comment: @popey Yes, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. The laptop is a an HP PROBOOK 450 G7

Comment: @waltinator not sure what I need to look for